# Replace last occurence of regexp in a string which has new lines (replace-regexp-in-string in Emacs)

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

I have this expression which I've parsed in Emacs:

```
mtcars %>%
head() %>%
select(mpg, cyl) %>%"
```

I want to replace the last `%>%` with whatever number of white spaces it might have *after* with *nothing*. So this works:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "%>% *$" "" "mtcars %>% head() %>% select(mpg, cyl) %>%")
```

and returns `mtcars %>% head() %>% select(mpg, cyl)`

But what I actually have is this:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "%>% *$" "" "mtcars %>%
head() %>%
select(mpg, cyl) %>%")
```

which returns a replacement of all %>% instead of the last:

```
mtcars
head()
select(mpg, cyl)
```

Anyone know how to achieve that with a string with new lines rather than in a single one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` doesn't match a newline. Tell the regex that newlines can also precede the the `%>%`, so the `\\1` will match all the previous lines:

```lisp
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)%>% *$" "\\1" "mtcars %>%
head() %>%
select(mpg, cyl) %>%")
```

Comment: I should ask this in a separate question but in case it's an easy one-liner to you. I want the above to work (which it does) but whenever the last line does not have a %>%, it should leave as is. So this: `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\)%>% *$" "\\1" "mtcars %>%
head() %>%
select(mpg, cyl) %>%
arrange(cyl)")` should not remove any %>%. I tried forcing this by adjusting the regex to only replace `%>% *$` up until the end of the string, but it keeps removing the last `%>%`. Any hint would be great!

Comment: @cimentadaj: Replace the `$` (end of line) by `\\'` (end of string).